Show $R+Sx+Tx^2 \equiv aR+aSy+aTy^2$ for $R,S,T$ symmetric functions of $x,y,z$ and $a \ne 1$ implies all of $R, S, T$ are all identically zero.
Suppose that $R,S,T$ are symmetric functions of the arbitrary independent variables $x,y,z$ and that $a \ne 1$. Can anyone help justify / prove / explain why the following identity is only possible if $R, S$ and $T$ are identically zero (where $Sx$ means $S$ multiplied by $x$, not $S(x)$ etc.): $$R+Sx+Tx^2 \equiv aR+aSy+aTy^2$$
It kind of feels natural that the identity is only possible if $R, S$ and $T$ are identically zero, i.e. that if they aren't then the various terms simply can't cancel in the way needed for arbitrary $x,y,z$ but I would like to make this more precise.  I'm also aware that it follows from $a+bx+cx^2 \equiv d+ex+fx^2$ that $a=d,b=e,c=f$ by comparing coefficients, and how this principle is justified, but this doesn't seem to apply here given that in the problem stated there are powers of $x$ on the left hand side and powers of $y$ on the right.
Is it as simple as arguing that, for example, the second term on the left, $Sx$ is a symmetric function of $x,y,z$ multiplied by $x$ and by inspection cannot be identical to any term on the right hand side?  Again, can this be justified/proved further?  It would only leave $p \equiv ap$ which isn't possible if $a \ne 1$.
For info, this comes from looking at Abel's 1824 proof that there is no quintic formula, where rather than $x,y,z$ there are five independent variables $y_1,y_2,\ldots y_5$ and $a$ is a fifth root of unity other than 1 and there are five symmetric function.  I don't think that these details are needed for the general principle though, is that right?  Abel just states that an identity such as this cannot happen, incidentally, without any further explanation.
Maybe I'm over-thinking something which is obvious, but any comments would be appreciated.

You probably want to assume that the functions are not identically zero.

@SeverinSchraven Thank you - yes, I'll add that to the question.

I think it an be proved by rearranging for $R$, i.e.
$$R \equiv \frac{S(ay-x)+T(ay^2-x^2)}{1-a}$$
The left hand side is symmetric in $x$, $y$ and $z$ by definition, but the right hand side clearly isn't, hence this is not possible.
It's interesting to note that this fails for the case of two variables, $x$ and $y$, i.e. it is possible to have $R+Sx \equiv aR+aSy$ with $a=-1$, this giving
$$R \equiv -\frac{S(x+y)}{2}$$
where the right hand side is symmetrical so it is possible.  In fact, $-(x+y)+2x$ is an example of an expression of the form $R+Sx$ which works, again for $a=-1$, i.e. $-(x+y)+2x \equiv (x+y)-2y$.
